# How to get a chekboxlist without using ng-repeat in html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

That I have some group of checkbox I have used , through that when I used to get a value it's getting an "undefined", plz suggest me - am I using a correct format or not. I am new in angularjs, thank you.

In the HTML:

```
<tbody>
   <tr data-skin="">
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="1" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval.1">
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
         <img src="~/Content/Tulips.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-skin="">
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="2" ng-model="bnnrdata.Banner.2">
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
         <img src="~/Content/Desert.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-skin="">
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="3" ng-model="bnnrdata.Banner.3">
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
         <img src="~/Content/Lighthouse.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
   </tr>
   <tr data-skin="">
      <td align="center">
         <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="4" ng-model="bnnrdata.Banner.4">
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
         <img src="~/Content/Penguins.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<div class="form-group" align="center">
   <button  ng-click="savebnnr()" ng-controller="bannerCtrl" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Skip & Continue..!</button>
</div>
```

In the AngularJS controller

```
angular.module('applictionmodule').controller("bannerCtrl", function ($scope, $http, InstanceService) {
    $scope.bnnrdata = {
        Banner: ''
    }
    $scope.savebnnr = function () {
        InstanceService.addinstance($scope.bnnrdata);
        $location.path('/Amminit');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think question is clear, all you need to get check box values orr something else??

Comment: @kernallora,   the value of the checkbox which user have checked,why i asked without ng-repeat means that the values r static, in case if we wnt any changes means we can change only in the html page only so

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need to get value for each of the check boxes. For that you have to have an array in controller.

```
$scope.bnnrdata = {
    Banner: [false, false, false, false];
}
```

Then in your HTML, you can assign each index of the array to each checkbox.
Like this.

```
<tr data-skin="">
    <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="1" ng-model="bnnrdata.Banner[0]">
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
          <img src="~/Content/Tulips.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Look closely at ng-model in the above HTMl. You just have to do that for every checkbox by just changing the index of the array like 1, 2, 3 and so on.

using `ng-repeat` will be better approach in doing that as per my advice.

Comment: why i asked without ng-repeat means that the values r static, in case if we wnt any changes means we can change only in the html page only so

Comment: The above solution will work without ng-repeat as well. I just gave advised in last. I gave the solution according to your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you get the values from `ng-submit` ?? This is form data submits along with user selected values.

```
<div ng-controller="bannerCtrl">


<form role="form" id="formNameID" novalidate class="form-horizontal form-content" name="formName" ng-submit="savebnnr(bnnrdata)">
  <div>

    <table>

      <tbody>
        <tr data-skin="">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="1" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval1">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">

            <img src="~/Content/Tulips.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-skin="">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="2" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval2">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">

            <img src="~/Content/Desert.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-skin="">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="3" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval3">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">

            <img src="~/Content/Lighthouse.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-skin="">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="radio" class="check" value="4" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval4">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">

            <img src="~/Content/Penguins.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Skip & Continue..!</button>
    </table </div>
</form>

</div>
```

IN Angular script you can get the object directly which user checked.

```
angular.module('applictionmodule').controller("bannerCtrl", function ($scope, $http, InstanceService) {

    $scope.savebnnr = function (bnnrdata) {
        InstanceService.addinstance($scope.bnnrdata);
        $location.path('/Amminit');
    }
});
```

bnnrdata has all checkbox list values. I hope it will be work for you.

Comment: Thank you..,. through this am getting only the true or false thats it ,it nt getting the value of the checkbox .,

Answer (score 0):

I think we need directive to achieve this.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="bannerCtrl">


<form role="form" id="formNameID" novalidate class="form-horizontal form-content" name="formName" ng-submit="savebnnr(bnnrdata)">
  <div>

    <table>

      <tbody>
        <tr data-skin="">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checkbox-value name="radio" class="check" value="1" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval1">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">

            <img src="~/Content/Tulips.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-skin="">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checkbox-value name="radio" class="check" value="2" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval2">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">

            <img src="~/Content/Desert.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-skin="">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checkbox-value name="radio" class="check" value="3" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval3">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">

            <img src="~/Content/Lighthouse.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="visibility:hidden"> ddd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-skin="">
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" checkbox-value name="radio" class="check" value="4" ng-model="bnnrdata.bannerval4">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">

            <img src="~/Content/Penguins.jpg" width="180" height="80" />
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <div class="form-group" align="center">
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Skip & Continue..!</button>
    </table </div>
</form>

</div>
```

JS:

```
  angular.module('applictionmodule').directive('checkboxValue', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)  {
          console.log(attrs.value);
          // we can perform operations with attribute and element values
        }
    }
    });
```